# WSO2 API Manager - WSO2 Analytics Server - Dropping wrongly formatted event Error

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-das

I'm using 2 instances of WSO2 APIM 2.1.0(offset 0 and offset 1) on the same node and I have pointed both of them to the WSO2 Analytics Server(offset 2).

In one of these instances(offset 1) multiple lines of the following error could be seen.

Any suggestion or troubleshooting step to overcome this error us highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

TID: [-1234] [] [2020-12-17 10:06:53,769] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} -  Dropping wrongly formatted event sent for -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.response:1.1.0 of event bundle with events 1
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:181)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.response:1.1.0 present in cache
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:166)
... 7 more

Comment: In APIM servers, have you pointed to the analytics server for analytics data publishing? What is the URL used? It should be tcp://localhost:7614

Comment: Hi @Pubci, Currently it is configured as tcp://localhost:7612 in the instance which gives the error. Should I change it to 7614?

Comment: yes, you need to change that

Comment: Hi @Pubci Now the following error occurs. Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7714. Could you please assist on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: use telnet and check what are the open ports?

Comment: @Pubci telnetted and only the port 7712 is reachable. Is there a specific configuration to enable port 7714?

Comment: You should connect to APIM Analytics node. I think it is 7713 and 7613.

Comment: @Pubci Changed the port to 7613. Now the SSL error is gone but the initial error could still be seen.